# How do I install fork of an npm package?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, git-fork

When I do:

```
rm -r node_modules \
    && npm i webpack-cleanup-plugin \
    && node -r webpack-cleanup-plugin -e 'console.log("success")'
```

It succeeds. But this way:

```
rm -r node_modules \
    && npm i bassarisse/webpack-cleanup-plugin \
    && node -r webpack-cleanup-plugin -e 'console.log("success")'
```

It fails with:

```
module.js:472
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-cleanup-plugin'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at module.js:656:12
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function.Module._preloadModules (module.js:655:12)
    at preloadModules (bootstrap_node.js:391:38)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:107:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:533:3
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @p0k8_ meaning what exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Original source code contain babel source code, so it should be precompiled before installation.

You may remove `lib` from `.gitignore`, compile with `npm run build` and commit compiled code in `lib` folder. Then it can be installed from github